# How to echo an array with -> association pointers PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative

How would I echo such a thing?

```
$referrals = affiliate_wp()->referrals->get_referrals( array( 'affiliate_id' => $affiliate_id,) );
```

If I just do:

```
echo $referrals;
```

it returns the value:

```
Array
```

I thought this was the proper Syntax:

```
echo $get_referrals[0]['affiliate_id'];
```

I just don't think I understand the `->` association pointers correctly.

Comment: The `->` parts are referencing properties and functions within a class. To determine your array structure, `print_r($referrals)` and decide how to access your values from there.

Comment: do a `var_dump($referrals)` or `print_r($referrals)` instead, should give the basic structure

Comment: var_dump($referrals) returns: array(0) { }                         and  print_r($referrals) returns: Array ( ), still unsure how to access values through this new information. BTW thank you all for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

`echo` can only be used with strings and numbers. To view the contents of structured data (arrays and objects) use `var_dump` or `print_r`.

```
echo '<pre>'; // So the layout is preserved
var_dump($referrals);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: var_dump($referrals) returns: array(0) { }, how might I use this knowledge to access the values

Comment: That's an empty array. So your query isn't finding any matches.